# Xamarin labs checkbox ios not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I asked same question on Xamarin forum but noone has answered my question.

I'm using X labs and my Codes like below.

My ContentPage of Portable project;

```
public class CheckBoxPage : ContentPage
{
    public CheckBoxPage()
    {
        CheckBox check = new CheckBox
        {
            TextColor = Color.Red,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        CheckBox unCheck = new CheckBox
        {
            TextColor = Color.Yellow,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                check, unCheck
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My android and iOS appearences are different. iOS appearence is not like a checkbox. However Android is working well. Why?

[image: Android Appearence is]

[image: iOs appearence is]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much

It is not editable about design. So I have a code example;

```
class CheckBox : Image
{
    public CheckBox(bool isChecked)
    {
        Resources = new ResourceDictionary();

        if(isChecked) 
            Resources.Add("ImageName", "checked.png");
        else
            Resources.Add("ImageName", "unchecked.png");

        var resourceName = Resources["ImageName"];
        Source = ImageSource.FromFile(resourceName.ToString());

        TapGestureRecognizer t = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        t.Tapped += OnScreenTapped;
        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(t);
    }

    public void OnScreenTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var resourceName = Resources["ImageName"];
        if (resourceName.ToString() == "unchecked.png")
        {
            Resources["ImageName"] = "checked.png";
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile("checked.png");
        }
        else
        {
            Resources["ImageName"] = "unchecked.png";
            Source = ImageSource.FromFile("unchecked.png");
        }
    }

    public bool isChecked()
    {
        var resourceName = Resources["ImageName"];
        if (resourceName.ToString() == "unchecked.png")
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Using this customCheckBox

```
CheckBox mychceck = new CheckBox(true);
```

this is more userfull for customizing design.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the same sample along with your code.

Turns out I am also getting a similar output in iOS.

This seems to be an issue with XLabs and after checking I found that there are several issues filed with [them](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20Checkbox).

A more appropriate one is this:

- https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/856#issuecomment-184024851

Probably, it would be best joining the same thread.

**Also**, you can give a try to this:

- https://libraries.io/nuget/Messier16.Forms.Checkbox

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Custom Checkbox in Xamarin IOS and Android

**Design Side:**

```
<Image Source="unchecked_checkbox" >
     <Image.GestureRecognizers >
         <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizerForCheckStaff" />
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**Coding Side:**

private void TapGestureRecognizerForCheckStaff(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        Image img = (Image)sender;
        var selectedImage = img.Source as FileImageSource;

        if (selectedImage.File == "unchecked_checkbox")
        {
            // perform action checkbox is checked;
            img.Source = "checked_checkbox";
        }

        if (selectedImage.File == "checked_checkbox")
        {
            // perform action when checkbox is unchecked
            img.Source = "unchecked_checkbox";
        }

    }
```